# I want to pull out the number of special characters and the number of vowels in each sentence using a matlab command

Tags: string, matlab

I have a cell in Matlab with 5 strings in it, each string being a sentence and I want to pull out the number of special characters and the number of vowels in each sentence using a Matlab command.  How would I do this?

Here is my code:

```
sentences={['Dogs are cool!'];['They love to have their bellies scratched!'];['They     love to run around and play in the grass.'];['Each normal year is equal to seven dog years.'];['Its sad when dogs die.']}
sentences1=length(sentences{1})
sentences2=length(sentences{2})
sentences3=length(sentences{3})
sentences4=length(sentences{4})
sentences5=length(sentences{5})
fprintf('There are %d, %d, %d, %d characters in each sentence respectively. ',     sentences1,sentences2,sentences3,sentences4,sentences5)
```

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't really have anything to do with your question, does it?

Comment: Yes it does. "sentences" is the cell and there are 5 strings in it. I want to use a matlab command to pull the number of special characters in each sentence.

Comment: Sure, but I don't really see how it helps us answer your question.  Have you made an attempt yet at writing some code in Matlab that does what you're asking for?  Show us that.

Comment: I have tried but I havent come up with anything that works. I think it involves a for loop.

Comment: How do you define "special character", exactly?

Comment: You start nicely by placing your data in a cell array. Now I really want to ask you to think twice before storing the results from calculations on that array in five individual named variables.

Answer (score 2):

If you define a special character as not a word character (`[a-z_A-Z0-9]`) and not whitespace:

```
cellfun(@(x) numel(regexp(x,'[^\w\s]')),sentences)
```

In your case, that is just one per sentence.  If you just want to count characters that are not word characters, which includes whitespace:

```
>> cellfun(@(x) numel(regexp(x,'[^\w]')),sentences)
ans =
     3
     7
    14
     9
     5
```

The vowels case is just:

```
 cellfun(@(x) numel(regexpi(x,'[aeiou]')),sentences)
```

Notice this now uses `regexpi` instead of `regexp` to ignore, case but you can also expand the pattern to `'[AEIOUaeiou]'` and use the normal `regexp`. Depending on your mood, you may also choose to use `[aeiouy]`.

Comment: All this time using Matlab and I never knew that it could evaluate regular expressions!

Comment: @nispio That must be such a revelation. Like when I discovered `bsxfun` only months ago :-)

Answer (score 1):

For vowels:

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU';
cellfun(@(s) sum(ismember(s,vowels)), sentences)
```

For special characters, do the same:

```
specialChar = '!?()-,;.'; % define your special characters
cellfun(@(s) sum(ismember(s,specialChar)), sentences)
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can try something like

```
vowels=['a'; 'e'; 'i' ;'o'; 'u'];
 Vowels_N=0;
 for ii=1:length(sentences)
     for jj=1:length(vowels)
         indx=find(vowels(jj),sentences{ii})
         Vowels_N=Vowels_N+length(indx);
     end
 end
```

probably not the most efficient way and might be buggy didn't test it just wrote it here 
you can do something similar for the special characters